# Polymer 1.0 : How to configure jshint for Polymer behaviours?

Tags: polymer, jshint

I have a globalize-behaviour.html file:

```
<script>
GlobalizeBehavior = {

  // https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html#definining-behaviors

  i18n: function(key) {
    return key;
  }

};
</script>
```

I am including this file in other custom-elements like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../globalize-behavior/globalize-behavior.html">
```

and using it like so (in global-element.html):

```
<script>
  (function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'global-element',
      behaviors: [GlobalizeBehavior],

      openAddTransDialog: function() {},

    });
  })();
</script>
```

And, here's the .jshintrc file:

```
{
  "node": true,
  "browser": true,
  "esnext": true,
  "bitwise": true,
  "camelcase": true,
  "curly": true,
  "eqeqeq": true,
  "immed": true,
  "indent": 2,
  "latedef": true,
  "noarg": true,
  "quotmark": "single",
  "undef": true,
  "unused": true,
  "globals": {
    "wrap": true,
    "unwrap": true,
    "Polymer": true,
    "Platform": true,
    "page": true,
    "app": true
  }
}
```

I am getting following error while running jshint:

> globalize-behavior.html line 2  col 1  'GlobalizeBehavior' is not defined.
>
> global-element.html line 104  col 17  'GlobalizeBehavior' is not defined.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add

```
"globals": {
    "GlobalizeBehavior": true
}
```

or:

```
"predef": [
    "GlobalizeBehavior"
]
```

to your `.jshintrc` file?

Comment: Fixed a typo in this answer. `prefed` was supposed to be `predef`